# Correct way to make lines appear over surfaces?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create lines(isocurves) appear over a surface in threejs. The surface was generated using verb nurbs.
They show up only on the front side of the surface; the back side has z-fighting.
[Front side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4QYp.jpg)
[Back Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpqLO.jpg)

I can't use wireframe to achieve this since that draws the diagonals.
How can I make it appear on both sides properly?

How I add the surface

```
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh( srf_ft.toThreeGeometry(), activeMat ));
```

How I add the line

```
getIsoCurves(srf_ft, 4).forEach(s => obj.add(new THREE.Line( s.toThreeGeometry(), matLine_white )));
```

Line Material

```
var matLine_white = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ linewidth: 80, color: 0xffffff, linecap: 'round', linejoin:  'round' });
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Not sure if this works in your case but you can try this material config for your lines:

depthWrite: false, polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: - 4

Comment: If you already have a working example that can draw on one side of the surface, how about just modifying the depth buffers so that the lines are always drawn over the mesh?

Comment: But that would override the lines which are actually meant to be occluded by an occluding surface.